# Server is not responding and accessible

Tags: networking, hard-drive, ssh, usb, power

A long power cut happened and I have one server with a weird behavior. It's an HP DL145 G2 without warranty :/

Impossible to make work a vga port or any usb port, same with PS/2 port
Impossible to connect to it via ssh. I plugged and unplugged the RAM, same with HDDs. I connected HDDs on another computer, they're fine. 
I also checked their filesystem. I tried to unplugged and plugged again everything I can in this server.

But when I start it, nothing it's like it's working but I can't access it in any way... I saw also the ethernet light.
Thx for the help.

I tried usb front port usb and back. I made sure that my test is set up before booting. I tried  a lot of configuration without success.

I tried the same cable configuration with the same model server and didn't get any issue to access it via vga and usb port